# Bootstrap carousel arrows on mobile moving up and down vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap carousel with caption but with little different style, practically, image is left (col-lg-6) , caption is right (col-lg-6)... See HTML and SCSS code for better understanding. Visual example - https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkJaM.png

What's the question? On mobile (col-md-12 for image and col-md-12 for caption) , when I resizing browser window, arrows moving up and down vertically, but always should be 30% from top, no matter how much screen was resized (mobile version).

top: 30% is not good, top: xx px also not good, transofm: translatey(-30%) not good, BUT top: 0; margin-top: 30% is perfectly. I guess that there is a better way to do that?

```css
#upgr-carousel-generic {
 background-color: #f3f3f3;
 
 .carousel-caption {
  color: #052453;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 14%;
  padding: 45px 90px 45px 27px;
  text-shadow: none;
  h3 {
   margin-bottom: 3px;
  }
 }
 .carousel-control {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-shadow: none;
     width: 65px;
     height: 65px;
     position: absolute;
     opacity: 1;
     top: 44%;
     &:hover, 
     &:focus {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     };
     [class^="icon-"] {
      font-size: 65px;
     }
 }
}

 @media (min-width: $screen-lg-min) {
  #upgr-carousel-generic .item .image img {
   width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
  }
 }

 @media (max-width: $screen-md-max) {
  #upgr-carousel-generic {
   .carousel-caption {
    padding: 28px 8.6px;
   }
   .carousel-control {
   width: 34px;
   height: 34px;
   top: 0;
   margin-top: 30%;
   [class^="icon-"] {
    font-size: 34px;
   }
    }
  }
 }
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row gridsystem">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div id="upgr-carousel-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 image">
                  <img src="../src/assets/images/_dev/carousel_image_1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Carousel Image 1">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-left">
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3 class="title">King gegen King</h3>
                    <p class="description">Auf ihrer Nordamerika-Reise 1939 treffen König Gorge VI. und seine Gemahlin, Queen Elizabeth, auf den kanadischen Premierminister William Lyon Mackenzie King. Das dabei entstandene Foto wurde später auf einem Wahlplakat des Premierministers verwender, König Gorg VI. jedoch daraus wegretuschiert. Ziel der Nordamerika-Reise war die Stärkung der Monarchie im Dominion Kanada, was der Intention Mackenzie Kings offenbar zuwiderlief.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>  
              </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 image">
                  <img src="../src/assets/images/_dev/carousel_image_2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Carousel Image 2">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-left">
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3 class="title">King gegen King</h3>
                    <p class="description">Auf ihrer Nordamerika-Reise 1939 treffen König Gorge VI. und seine Gemahlin, Queen Elizabeth, auf den kanadischen Premierminister William Lyon Mackenzie King. Das dabei entstandene Foto wurde später auf einem Wahlplakat des Premierministers verwender, König Gorg VI. jedoch daraus wegretuschiert. Ziel der Nordamerika-Reise war die Stärkung der Monarchie im Dominion Kanada, was der Intention Mackenzie Kings offenbar zuwiderlief.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>  
              </div> 
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" title="Previous" href="#upgr-carousel-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-ic-arrow-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" title="Next" href="#upgr-carousel-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-ic-arrow-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>  
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need add this to your `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

#### then you can use vw or vh:

```
Unit    Description
em      Relative to the font-size of the element (2em means 2 times the size of the current font) Try it
ex      Relative to the x-height of the current font (rarely used) Try it
ch      Relative to width of the "0" (zero)
rem     Relative to font-size of the root element
vw      Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport* Try it
vh      Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport* Try it
vmin    Relative to 1% of viewports* smaller dimension Try it
vmax    Relative to 1% of viewports* larger dimension Try it
%
```

more about units check this link: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

## What is The Viewport?

The viewport is the user's visible area of a web page.

The viewport varies with the device, and will be smaller on a mobile phone than on a computer screen.

Before tablets and mobile phones, web pages were designed only for computer screens, and it was common for web pages to have a static design and a fixed size.

For more info you can read it here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: I already have meta name viewport in <head> tag. You gave me a good idea, but vh does not work good - same effect as with px, but 30vw (viewport) works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: @MileMijatovic cool, I updated my post too, have more info, in case it will help others in the futures. Please upvote if it is helping you, accept the answer if solves your problem, thanks!